# get captcha image from site

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, captcha

I 'd like to get captcha images.
I have captured request to get images using fiddler.

this is raw text of request.

> GET http://api.minteye.com/slider/image.ashx?CaptchaId=4162&PublicKey=76dd4b3f-92d2-4d29-9cb8-740ccfca4fe4&w=300&h=250&dumm=635086078045177660&reqid=e112b222-0f38-4309-9ab4-791aa11590d8-2eb9&img=1 HTTP/1.1
>   Host: api.minteye.com
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
>   Accept: */*
>   Referer: http://abc-site.com/?param=value
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
>   Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
>   Cookie: __utma=219856005.121997545.1372326418.1372834638.1372992381.5; __utmz=219856005.1372992381.5.2.utmcsr=api.minteye.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/; ASP.NET_SessionId=oh543ydsa2z033ybv2cg0wwi; ExchangeAds=10959011

After that, i have made request header and send it to getresponse.
but i can't get any image.(can't see anything even in fiddler)

this is my code.

```
CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();    
        request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://api.minteye.com/slider/image.ashx?CaptchaId=4162&PublicKey=76dd4b3f-92d2-4d29-9cb8-740ccfca4fe4&w=300&h=250&dumm=4211089392&reqid=8075f74e-7878-4a9a-a5a0-3c21b5fbfb79-5f5f&img=5");            
        request.KeepAlive = true;            
        request.Accept = "*/*";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36";
        request.Referer = "http://abc-site.com/?param=value";                        
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
        request.CookieContainer = cookie;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

While running this code, fiddler captures requests and its response, but doesn't get any image.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you give me your sources, i can look how you became the requestID,
with this requestID can you make the URL for this images.
With this URL, you can download it with a simple WebClient ;)